# Access violation starting Tomcat from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

When I try to start Server Tomcat 8 in Eclipse, I have this error:

> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>
> EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ffd233a2bbd,
>   pid=6852, tid=3720  JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
>   (8.0_66-b18) (build 1.8.0_66-b18) Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit
>   Server VM (25.66-b18 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
>
> Problematic frame:  C  [WS2_32.dll+0x2bbd]

It failed to write a core dump, and minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows.

What is the reason? How to fix it?

Comment: I suspect hardware problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have Eclipse, Eclipse Tomcat plugin (Server connector), Java used for the Tomcat in same JVM arhitecture. Either 32 or 64 bit.

Check server connector settings in: Window/Preferences/Server/Runtime environments/Edit. For the java version, be sure that you download 32 bit Eclipse.

In the past I found that Java 32, Eclipse 32 and 32 bit plugins have lesser bugs and in general work more stable than their 64 bit part.

I see no problem if you develop on 32 bit platform, and in production you have of course 64 bit platform.

Comment: Thank You for your answer, but I don't think this is the problem, because I have install Eclipse 64 bit ,and before it worked. The problem could be in the WS2_32.dll , I think that a malware damages it

Comment: I did not say eclipse 64 does not work. I just wanted to point out, that before spending days troubleshooting any error like this, you must first make sure that 3 different software involved uses same JVM. Namely Eclipse, Eclipse Plugin, Tomcat 8, and JVM used for project compilation and Tomcat's jvm. I had problems just like this if these things did not use same JVM. Just give it a try, it should be 20 minutes of work. If tomcat starts standalone way, how malware can damage dll?